# Generics covariance in constraint

Tags: c#, generics

I am currently having trouble with generics in C# and I have a solution, but I am looking for a cleaner one. I have generally a pretty good C# knowledge, so I am not sure, if what I want exists.

I have a generic base class, with nested constraints

```
public abstract class BaseParam { }

public abstract class BaseProcess<TParam> : IProcess
   where TParam : BaseParam
{
    public TParam Parameter { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseTask<TProc, TParam>
   where TProc : BaseProcess<TParam>, new()
   where TParam : BaseParam, new()
{
    public IProcess Create()
    {
        var proc = new TProc();
        proc.Param = new TParam();
        return proc;
    }
}
```

Now I could create a couple of derivations and this worked for a while

```
public class SomeParam : BaseParam { }

public class SomeProcess : BaseProcess<SomeParam> { }

public class SomeTask : BaseTask<SomeProcess, SomeParam> { }
```

The problem occurs when I start mixing the inheritance levels like so

```
public class SuperParam : SomeParam { }

// The next line won't compile
public class SuperTask : BaseTask<SomeProcess, SuperParam> { }
```

I know it does not compile because Covariance only exists on interfaces and `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` are technically two different classes. However the code inside would work just fine. What I want is to write a "covariant constraint" like:

```
public abstract class BaseTask<TProc, TParam>
   where TProc : BaseProcess<TProcParam>
   where TProcParam : BaseParam
   where TParam : TProcParam
{
}
```

I tried using `ISomeProc<TParam>` because interfaces are covariant, but that only works for assignments, not lower bounds. Functional Workaround is declaring an additional type argument, but that is not pretty enough:

```
public abstract class BaseTask<TProc, TProcParam, TParam>
   where TProc : BaseProcess<TProcParam>
   where TProcParam : BaseParam
   where TParam : TProcParam
{
}
```

**CompilerError:**

```
The type 'SomeProcess' cannot be used as type parameter 'TProc' in the
generic type or method 'BaseTask<TProc,TParam>'. There is no implicit
reference conversion from 'SomeProcess' to 'BaseProc<SuperParam>'.
```

**Edit:** I understand some more explanation is required. Within the class I don't need properties of `SuperParam`, only `BaseParam`, but it should be an instance of `SuperParam`. However we read the `SuperTask` definition with reflection and create an editor. And that editor must know what object it is supposed to create.

**Question:** Is there any way to design the constraints of `BaseTask` so that it respects covariance without adding the extra parameter `TProcParam`? I could come up with workarounds, but I feel like there is an easier way.

Comment: Hi, just for clarity but can you post the compiler error as well?

Comment: "However the code inside would work just fine" how do you know this?  It's hard to know that without seeing the "code inside".

Comment: Ok, you tried something, and it didn't work but i wonder what is your question ?

Comment: You base class is not, cannot be, will never be, covariant in `TParam` because `Parameter` has a setter. It also happens that C# does not allow classes to be variant (a big oversight, in my opinion) but even if it did you couldn't make it covariant.

Comment: If you want that your type parameter is covariant. You can use the out keyword in generic interfaces and delegates. Try to use the approach of @ArturoMenchaca

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson yes, that happened while trying port the example. Sadly I am not allowed to paste the real classes.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for your problem is highly dependent on how are implemented your classes, but if you can convert `BaseProcess<>` to a co-variant interface `IBaseProcess<>`:

```
public interface IBaseProcess<out TParam>
   where TParam : BaseParam
{
}
```

And declare `BaseTask` as:

```
public abstract class BaseTask<TProc, TParam>
    where TProc : IBaseProcess<BaseParam>
    where TParam : BaseParam
{
}
```

Then, `SomeProcess` as:

```
public class SomeProcess : IBaseProcess<SomeParam> { }
```

You would be able to declare `SuperTask` as you want:

```
public class SuperTask : BaseTask<SomeProcess, SuperParam> { }
```

Comment: I could, but then the compiler could not tell me, that `SomeProcess` and `SuperProcess` are compatible. Giving it some thought, what I want to do might not make sense for the compiler - I want him to check if it is compatible, without being to strict about it...

Comment: @Toxantron: I think there is no way to do so without an intermediate type, because on one hand you want a processor (first generic parameter) more specialized than `BaseParam` (can only be with covariance or adding a second generic parameter) and on the other hand a param valid for the processor, but not necessarily of the same type (third generic parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and further inspection I noticed two things:

1. The example is incomplete, which distracted from the problem at hand.
2. What I want to do is impossible for the compiler to understand

The solution I will go with for now is the a combination of the workaround and an effort to keep the default behavior clean:

```
// Use workaround on BaseTask
public abstract class BaseTask<TProc, TProcParam, TParam>
   where TProc : BaseProcess<TProcParam>
   where TProcParam : BaseParam
   where TParam : TProcParam
{
}

// Generic shortcut overload
public abstract class BaseTask<TProc, TParam> : BaseTask<TProc, TParam, TParam>
   where TProc : BaseProcess<TProcParam>
   where TParam : TProcParam
{
}
```

This way I can do both:

```
public class SomeTask : BaseTask<SomeProcess, SomeParam> { }

public class SuperTask : BaseTask<SomeProcess, SomeParam, SuperParam> { }
```